# Can I reduce the Circular Buffer to "1"? Is that a good idea?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

By default, there are a default of 1,000 messages stored in the ring buffer on the server.

It doesn't make sense for me to send a lagging client 1,000 updates, but rather just the most recent update.  In WCF I can do this by using volatile data.

I suppose I can emulate a volatile approach by reducing the buffer to "1", but not sure if this can be configured on a per hub basis, or ideally, on a per method basis.

Does it matter if I use hubs or persistent connections with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you set the [DefaultMessageBufferSize](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS563US563&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=defaultmessagebuffersize) to 1, SignalR ensures each buffer will hold at least 32 messages.

The primary purpose of this minimum buffer size is to ensure that SignalR's long-polling transport works somewhat reliably. If the buffer size was actually 1, a client connected via long-polling would be very likely to miss messages between polls.

I understand that there are some applications where *only* the last message matters. Unfortunately, as of now, SignalR does not have a "volatile" messaging configuration. Setting the buffer size to 32 is about as good as it gets. At least the client shouldn't lag too far behind with that small of a buffer size.

You are correct in assuming that there are multiple buffers, but buffer sizes cannot be configured individually. SignalR creates one ring buffer per "signal". A "signal" can be a connection id, group name, user name, PersistentConnection name (for when you call Connection.Broadcast), and Hub name (for when you call `Clients.All`). If you use `Clients.All` inside of multiple methods in a single hub, all those calls will end up in a single buffer.

If you want to configure another SignalR endpoint with different settings inside of the same application you can do the following:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Configuration;
using Owin;

// ...

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // The following will setup a SignalR endpoint at "/signalr"
    // using settings from GlobalHost
    app.MapSignalR();

    var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();
    var configuration = resolver.Resolve<IConfigurationManager>();

    configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 32;

    // By specifying or own dependency resolver, we tell the
    // "/volatile" endpoint not to use settings from GlobalHost
    app.MapSignalR("/volatile", new HubConfiguration
    {
        Resolver = resolver
    });
}

// ...
```

Comment: How do I configure this on a per signal basis?

Comment: You cannot configure buffer sizes per signal. At best, you could map two SignalR endpoints with different `DefaultMessageBufferSize`s, but that would require an extra concurrent connection per client.

Comment: OK I'll try to configure two endpoints.  I'm assuming I can do this on the same machine.  Is `GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize` a singleton?  How can I configure other endpoints on the same machine?

Comment: GlobalHost.Configuration is implemented as `return GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConfigurationManager>()`. If you pass your own resolver in via the HubConfiguration, GlobalHost will not be used.