# Signalr LongPollDelay and the buffer

Tags: signalr, mobile-safari

We have Safari mobile clients that are affected by one of their 5 connections being blocked by signalr.  We have used the solution propped here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1406#issuecomment-14284093

Where we have these settings changed to the following for signalR 2.x

- GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout =
  TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
- GlobalHost.Configuration.LongPollDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);

We are sending notifications from the server to the client with no message queue or acknowledgement framework.  We don’t need to guarantee message delivery but we do want there to be a high probability of success.  We think this should be possible due to our low message rate and a buffer size of 1000.  However we have some questions:

1. Are messages held in a queue while the LongPollDelay occurs?  Should
   they be sent during the next long poll using the settings above?
2. Our tests with a single message being sent during a 2 minute
   LongPollDelay suggest that they are not retrieved during the 1
   second long poll request that follows.  Are there any reasons for
   this i.e. buffer flushing after 1 minute?
3. Does ConnectionTimeout affect all transports?
4. If ConnectionTimeout applies to all transports is there a way of
   setting this for only Safari mobile users i.e. have two connections
   available and use agent detection to point to a specific connection?
5. Is there a way of setting the LongPollDelay so that this also only
   applied to only Safari mobile users?

All advice welcome and appreciated, Matt

**[FOLLOW-UP QUESTIONS]**

Thanks that helps a lot.  We have retried with 30secs LongPollDelay and it works as expected.  I have a couple of follow-up questions that you/someone might care to comment on:

1) During testing we also see the client sending a ping request to the server roughly every 5 minutes. Why is the ping period set to 5 minutes when the disconnect period is so much shorter, and what is the purpose of the client pinging the server if it assumes it is disconnected via an alternative mechanism.

2) w.r.t. Different configurations for different clients.  Could we not set up another SignalR endpoint and point only Safari mobile to this?  Something like the response to this post:
[Can I reduce the Circular Buffer to "1"? Is that a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263177/can-i-reduce-the-circular-buffer-to-1-is-that-a-good-idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are correct that the SignalR will queue/buffer messages. Even if there wasn't a LongPollDelay configured, SignalR needs to do this because there is always a chance that messages are sent while clients are repolling/reconnecting.
2. SignalR assumes that the client has disconnected if the client hasn't been connected to the server within the last [DisconnectTimeout](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnecttimeout). Once the DisconnectTimeout triggers, SignalR will call OnDisconnected and clear any message buffers belonging to the supposedly disconnected client so it doesn't leak memory. The DisconnectTimeout defaults to 30 seconds which is far less than the 2 minute LongPollDelay you configured, so that explains this behavior.
3. The [ConnectionTimeout](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#connectiontimeout) only affects long polling unless you've disabled keep alives. If keep alives are disabled, it applies to all transports.
4. There is no way to selectively configure the ConnectionTimeout for specific types of clients. But as I stated, it only affects long polling by default.
5. There is no way to selective configure the LongPollDelay for specific types of clients.

Comment: Thank you, I added a follow-up question for you to consider.

Comment: Generally it is better to ask follow up questions as new SO questions, but I'll answer here anyway. 1) Pings are used to keep session cookies active which requires making new requests. 2) You could configure multiple endpoints, but if you want the endpoints to communicate with eachother they will need to share an IMessageBus. This can be achieved using SignalR's IDependencyResolver. Note the two endpoints should *not* share a IDependencyResolver, just the IMessageBus.